# How are sounds usually handled in a Redux application?

Tags: react-native, audio, redux

I am writing a React-Native countdown timer application in which I want to play sounds at certain seconds as well as during some other events. I couldn't find much information about how to handle sound loading and playing sounds in a Redux application. I found one implementation where the sound objects were stored in the Redux store, and the sounds were played using Redux middleware, like this ([source](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/base/sounds/middleware.js)):

```
MiddlewareRegistry.register(store => next => action => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case PLAY_SOUND:
        _playSound(store, action.soundId);
        break;

    return next(action);
});

/**
 * Plays sound from audio element registered in the Redux store.
 *
 * @param {Store} store - The Redux store instance.
 * @param {string} soundId - Audio element identifier.
 * @private
 * @returns {void}
 */
function _playSound({ getState }, soundId) {
    const sounds = getState()['features/base/sounds'];
    const sound = sounds.get(soundId);

    if (sound) {
        if (sound.audioElement) {
            sound.audioElement.play();
        } else {
            logger.warn(`PLAY_SOUND: sound not loaded yet for id: ${soundId}`);
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn(`PLAY_SOUND: no sound found for id: ${soundId}`);
    }
}
```

However, the Redux docs recommend not to store non-serializable data in the store, which this implementation violates.

I have an idea of storing an array of pending sounds in the Redux store and have a container listening for changes to this array, playing the sound in turn and removing it using an action creator. Does this sound like a reasonable approach or are there better ways to handle sounds in Redux?